# Class not found com.google.gson.Gson exception in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gson

I am using Gson in the web application that I'm developing on Google App Engine. I put the gson-1.1.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder. It complies and deploy fine. But giving Class not Found exception when application serving requests. Can any one please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does this error happen on local, appengine or both?

Comment: @Rohan: It happens on local. I did not deploy it to appengine yet. I'm facing few issues doing that. Thats a different issue.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your gson jar to 1.7, remove all older gson jars, add the new one, clean the project and see if it deploys correctly.